# What data structure would allow me to analyze information from a text file?

Tags: java, parsing

I am given a "medical" text file. 
This text file has Patient Names, Age, Gender, Blood Pressure, level of response (unresponsive, Alert, etc), heartbeat, etc of 15 people.

Each person and their information is separated by each line.

What I want to do is parse all their info and analyze each piece to see what level priority they would be in the ER.

I'm having difficulty with picking a data structure to hold the information for each patient while also allowing me to analyze it.

I thought I could use a priority Queue but that would allow me to analyze their information in a practical way.

I also considered a Hashmap but I don't know what I would use as a Key to find the patients.

Comment: List of `Patient` objects ?

Comment: List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>(); Use like this.

Comment: I meant a list datastructure like  `ArrayList`

Comment: I actually thought about using a List. How would I categorize each section of the information given? Like the first variable names, second gender etc? How can I reflect that?

Comment: Can you please provide some example content of your file?

Comment: Can an ArrayList hold both integer and String variables?

Comment: Create a `Patient` class that will hold information about single patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to do that. I would recommend creating a `Patient` class, like this:

```
public class Patient {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    // ...

    public Patient(String name, int age /* , ... */) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        // ...
    }
    // getter for all fields
}
```

You now can read the file and map each line to a `Patient` object and create a list of patients. To do that one way would be to use `Files.lines()` and Java Streams:

```
List<Patient> patients = Files.lines(Paths.get("your-patients-file"))
        .map(line -> line.split(", "))
        .map(parts -> new Patient(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) /*, ... */))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Finally you can use that list for whatever you like to do with it.